# Rails 3 console having clause with two conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I looking for Users who might have multiple accounts. The following query from the console works:

```
User.find(:all, :group => :email, :having => "count(*) >1")
```

However, there are some accounts that have an email of 'nil' which I would like to exclude. I tried:

```
User.find(:all, :group => :email, :having => "count(*) >1 and email is not nil")
```

...without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.where.not(email: nil).having('COUNT(*) > 1').group(:email)
```

Comment: Does not seem to like the `.not`. I get the error `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+)`

Comment: `.not` might be Rails 4.  `where('email is not null')` should work in Rails 3.

Answer (score 1):

To add conditions, append a "where" clause right after your model class.

```
User.where("email IS NOT NULL").having(conditions).group(column)
```